# OpenESB 2.3 GlassFish - Logging IP Address of each and every request

Tags: glassfish, soa, esb, bpel, open-esb

Currently I am facing an issue with GlassFish OpenESB (net beans impl) 2.3. Which is the latest version.

I am receiving numerous http requests on my server on an invalid URL which does not exist, Hence the log file prints following log as many as 2/3 times a second. It seems like a thread and a loop that is sending me these request.

> [#|2013-07-12T16:04:10.335+0500|WARNING|sun-appserver2.1|com.sun.jbi.httpsoapbc.embedded.JAXWSGrizzlyRequestProcessor|_ThreadID=136;_ThreadName=httpWorkerThread-9080-3;/MyProject/DummyTransactions;9080;_RequestID=75ec0a79-46bb-4bfd-bfaf-3ff27cc454dd;|HTTPBC-W00652:
>   No web service mapping found for requested URL
>   /MyProject/DummyTransactions, port 9,080|#]

Is there a way to log each and every request's IP address and then also a way to block them. Any of these two will be very helpful.

thanks in advance